# Why is YAML throwing float ArgumentErrors on strings?

Tags: ruby, string, yaml, psych

I have some nested strings in a complex hash that triggers "ArgumentError" exceptions. What's the best practiced way in dealing with this?

```
require 'yaml'
{
    a: 'hello',
    b: [{f:'hello',g:Hash.new,i:{a:'hello'}}],
    c: {e:"+."}
}.to_yaml #=> `Float': invalid value for Float(): "+" (ArgumentError)
```

Full error dump:

```
/Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb:99:in `Float': invalid value for Float(): "+" (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb:99:in `tokenize'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:272:in `visit_String'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:128:in `accept'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:324:in `block in visit_Hash'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:322:in `each'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:322:in `visit_Hash'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:128:in `accept'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:324:in `block in visit_Hash'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:322:in `each'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:322:in `visit_Hash'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:128:in `accept'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:92:in `push'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:244:in `dump'
    from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/core_ext.rb:14:in `psych_to_yaml'
```

Comment: Error not reproducible with ruby 2.0, what version are you using?

Comment: `ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]`

Comment: That's very strange. This syntax is supported by 1.9.* and 2.0. I know for a fact that this won't work in 1.8.7, due to the hash syntax.

Comment: Well I'm first aware of this error because my ubuntu (`ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]`) server threw it at me. Then I tested it locally on my OSX machine, and same problem.

Comment: It works fine for me with 1.9.3p125 but I get the same error with 2.0.0p0.

Comment: It definitely seems like a bug; it's trying to parse that last string as a float.

Comment: Got the same error, using `ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]`

Comment: What I found is in version 1.3.4 psych is silently rescue this error, but in version 2.0.0 it is without `begin rescue` cover. So it rises this error.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the bundled psych.  Patching `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb` at line 99 from:

```
Float(string.gsub(/[,_]|\.$/, ''))
```

to:

```
Float(string.gsub(/[,_]|\.$/, '')) rescue ArgumentError
```

fixes the issue.  This is essentially what's in the psych gem as well as the Ruby 1.9 bundled version.

If you'd rather not patch your Ruby, using the psych-1.3.4 gem is another option; just be sure to `require 'psych'` rather than `'yaml'`:

```
gem 'psych', '=1.3.4'
require 'psych'
{a: 'hello', b: [{f:'hello',g:Hash.new,i:{a:'hello'}}], c: {e:"0+."}}.to_yaml
# => "---\n:a: hello\n:b:\n- :f: hello\n  :g: {}\n  :i:\n    :a: hello\n:c:\n  :e: 0+.\n"
```

Comment: That's a typo.  It should be `require 'psych'`. ;-)

Comment: hah, yeah that's what I meant. But also same error. I just copied and pasted your answer, rather than correct the type :P

Comment: If you're getting the *same* error, I suspect you're in the same irb session in which you've already `require`d 'yaml'.

Comment: Not sure, Rubymine is my IDE. so it should reload? It works for you?

Comment: Actually, sorry -- I don't know why, but the psych gem isn't working for me now either.  I don't know what I did before when it seemed to work.  `to_yaml` is still calling the bundled one.  The patch definitely still works.

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm off my game today.  You just need to be sure to use the non-bundled version of psych.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be reproduced with a simpler example:

```
"+.".to_yaml
```

This appears to be a bug in the version of psych bundled with ruby 2.0.0 (and other versions, I'm sure):

```
  when FLOAT
    if string == '.'
      @string_cache[string] = true
      string
    else
      Float(string.gsub(/[,_]|\.$/, ''))
    end
```

The problem is that that "+." looks like a valid floating point number like +.5.

This is fixed in Ruby 2.2.1 (or probably an earlier version), which specifically checks for the case where there may be a leading sign (+ or -):

```
  when FLOAT
    if string =~ /\A[-+]?\.\Z/
      @string_cache[string] = true
      string
    else
      Float(string.gsub(/[,_]|\.$/, ''))
    end
```